# using Yii CDateTimeParser to generate timestamp for the very end of the day (23:59:59)

Tags: php, datetime, yii, unix-timestamp, yii1.x

I am using Yii's CDateTimeParser:parse function to generate a UNIX timestamp from a 'human UK date'

```
$timestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse('29/10/2015', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

This works fine, however I need to also generate a second timestamp that will a timestamp for the date entered but at the very end of the day e.g at 23:59:59 (just before midnight).

I know that I could do this using DateTime() quite easily but i'm sure the Yii guys must have thought about this already :)

I have tried doing this below but it doesn't appear to work (returns FALSE)

```
$midnight_timestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse('15/10/2015 23:59:59', 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i:s');
```

Any ideas?? I am using Yii 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use correct date time format in `CDateTimeParser::parse()`.

So, Correct way is

```
$midnight_timestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse('15/10/2015 23:59:59', 'dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:s');
```

More info [CDateTimeParser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CDateTimeParser)